# run custom code when contact form 7 gets deleted?

Tags: wordpress

i am using wp-contact form 7 and i want to delete my custom table row data when i delete any contact form from contact form's admin menu. I tried hours on google but didn't find anything working.Is there any hook or working example for this purpose(like - wpcf7_delete or something ). Please provide help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since CF7 using custom post type called 'wpcf7_contact_form', you can use post related hooks & check for that post type, like that:

```
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'my_func' );
function my_func( $postid ){
    // We check if the post type isn't ours and just return 
    if ( get_post_type( $postid ) != 'wpcf7_contact_form' ) return;
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Note that you can use other post-delete-related hooks, such as 'before_delete_post', 'delete_post', 'deleted_post', etc. It depends on when & what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Codeartist for your response,i will try this.Hope this would solve my problem.